Makefile In which cases does it work from the shell?
I wrote a makefile like below:
.SILENT:

test3:
    PARAM_3=$(shell echo "Shell variable")

When i run make test3, it gives below error:
/bin/sh: 1: variable: not found
make: *** [Makefile:5: test3] Error 127

But i run it on the terminal like below:
$ PARAM_3=$(echo "Shell variable")


make runs everything in the shell. The crucial difference is that (absent .ONESHELL:) each recipe line gets run in a separate shell instance. This is a very common beginner FAQ.

@tripleee I really couldn't get the answer to my first question from the link you sent. I think you just read the title and closed the question...

To the extent that I can understand what you are asking, the duplicate is precisely about what I also pointed out in the first comment. We only permit one question per question; if you have multiple, perhaps ask a new question specifically about the other thing (whatever that is) and explain it more clearly, ideally with a [mre]

Oh, you're asking why make variables don't require quoting? They just don't. make doesn't have the concept of quoting.

@tripleee i simpified the question

It's still just a trivial lack of quoting. You are assigning PARAM3=Shell for the duration of attempting to execute variable as a command. I added a second duplicate to cover this. See also When to wrap quotes around a shell variable

Separately, don't use .SILENT: while you are trying to figure something out

Agree especially with the last item.  Why are you adding .SILENT:?  It's like running your compiler with output sent to /dev/null then trying to figure out why the compilation failed.  If you remove .SILENT: you'll see the problem.  The $(shell echo "Shell variable") is run by make and outputs the string Shell variable (note no quotes of course).  Make substitutes that into the text of your recipe, and it runs the shell command PARAM_3=Shell variable (again, no quotes!!)  If you run THAT at the command line you'll get the same error as your makefile.
